# django comment_update view: page_not_found 404

Tags: python, django

при попытке обновления коментария оставленного к посту с post.pk=20 функция переводит на страницу на которой post.pk = comment.pk(тоесть 45). такого поста нет. и естественно выдает ошибку.
что я сделал не так указывая ключевые аргументы для поста и коментария?

```
@login_required
def add_comment(request, pk):
    post = get_object_or_404(Post, pk=pk)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = CommentForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            comment = form.save(commit=False)
            comment.post = post
            comment.user = request.user
            comment.save()
            return redirect('post-detail', pk=post.pk)
    else:
        form = CommentForm()
    template_name = 'blog/add_comment.html'
    context = {'form': form}
    return render(request, template_name, context)


def comment_update(request, pk):
    template_name = 'blog/comment_update.html'
    post = get_object_or_404(Post, pk=pk)
    form = CommentForm(request.POST or None, instance=post)

    if form.is_valid():
        comment = form.save(commit=False)
        comment.post = post
        comment.user = request.user
        comment.save()
        return redirect('post-detail', pk=post.pk)
    context = {'form': form}
    return render(request, template_name, context)
```

forms

```
from django import forms
from .models import Comment


class CommentForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Comment
        fields = ['body']
```

comment_update.html

```
{% extends 'blog/base.html'%}
{% load crispy_forms_tags %}


{% block content %}

    <div class="content-section">
        <form method="POST">
            {% csrf_token %}
            <fieldset class="form-group">
                <legend class="border-bottom mb-4">comment</legend>
                {{ form|crispy }}
            </fieldset>
            <div class="form-group">
                <button class="btn btn-outline-info" type="submit">Post</button>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: `def comment_update(request, pk):` тут точно pk поста приходит?

Comment: да, и вместо pk поста, оно  захватывает pk комментария, и пробует перейти по ссылке /blog/post/comment.pk/...

Comment: @GeorgePotapov В `form = CommentForm(request.POST or None, instance=post)` `instance` должен быть объектом `Comment`, ведь? Вы передаете туда объект `Post`.

Comment: так пробовал, и уже при добавлении помечает его ошибкой undefined name

Comment: а пробовали `from .models import Comment` ?

Comment: да, модель коммента импортирована.